# Windows 8.1 reboot upon reaching the logo

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8.1, grub

I have a HDD which was used just for Windows 8.1. That is, the HDD had two partitions, system reserved and Windows.

Now I got a SSD and switched back to Linux as my main OS, but yet I have the HDD with Windows. Grub detects the Windows system and so, it does add it to its menu entries. However, whenever I try to get into Windows, upon reaching the loading screen where the blue logo shows up, the system reboot.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try using the repair-funktion of your Windows install CD/DVD, as this sounds like grub found the windows boot loader and booted, but windows chickened out.

Hopefully, this won't destroy grub, if so reinstall grub your Linux-LiveCD afterwards

Comment: it has something to do with Grub. Just tried to boot up choosing the HDD at BIOS, and it worked.